# What will happen to the Leases when the active NameNode failed in HDFS?

Tags: java, hdfs

HDFS uses a standby NameNode in case the active NameNode fails. In that case, what will happen to the Leases? Does the client need to apply for a new lease, or will the original lease be retained? In the second case, what mechanism does HDFS use to do this?

I've looked at many documents about leases, but none of them mention this issue.